# Automatically save form in folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I wrote a script in Google Apps Script that creates new forms from Google Sheets.
How can I save the form automatically in a specific folder in the drive?

Comment: Please provide more info. What do you mean by "creates new forms"? (Google Form, HTML Form, Google Doc "paper form", PDF form...) Is your form currently being saved somewhere? How? Where? (Did you try getting the form's ID and then using the Drive service to add the file to a specific folder?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say, but let's assume you're creating a Google Form, e.g. like this:

```js
var form=FormApp.create('My form');
```

In that case, here's a function that will add the Drive File of that form to a Drive Folder that you specify. Note - this function can support Documents, Spreadsheets, and other file types... any Google Apps Script object that has a `getId()` method and can also be represented as a Drive File.

```js
/**
 * Places file for given item into given folder.
 * If the item is an object that does not support the getId() method or
 * the folder is not a Folder object, an error will be thrown.
 * From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38042090/1677912
 *
 * @param {Object}  item     Any object that has an ID and is also a Drive File.
 * @param {Folder}  folder   Google Drive Folder object.
 */
function saveItemInFolder(item,folder) {
  var id = item.getId();  // Will throw error if getId() not supported.
  folder.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(id));
}
```

Example:

```js
// Create temporary form 
var form=FormApp.create('Delete me');
// Get temporary folder
var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Delete me').next();

saveItemInFolder(form,folder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the DriveApp to actually move the form if you have the IDs

[Like so, but you'd do it only for 1 file (your form ID)](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders)